# geoip.location missing after logstash parse of apachelog , Kibana map Visualizer Not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I used logstash to insert data to elastic search and conf file looks like

```
  grok {
             match => [
         "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}",
         "message" , "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}"
         ]
         overwrite => [ "message" ]
      }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
  geoip {
      source => "clientip"
    }
```

Now in Elastic Search mapping is done as

```
{                                                                                                                                                        
   "response" => "200",                                                                                                                              
      "geoip" => {                                                                                                                                   
          "timezone" => "Asia/Kolkata",                                                                                                              
     "country_code3" => "IN",                                                                                                                        
          "location" => {                                                                                                                            
        "lon" => 80.2833,                                                                                                                            
        "lat" => 13.0833                                                                                                                             
    },                                                                                                                                               
       "region_code" => "TN",                                                                                                                        
      "country_name" => "India",                                                                                                                     
         "longitude" => 80.2833,                                                                                                                     
         "city_name" => "Chennai",                                                                                                                   
       "region_name" => "Tamil Nadu",                                                                                                                
          "latitude" => 13.0833,                                                                                                                     
    "continent_code" => "AS",                                                                                                                        
       "postal_code" => "600073",                                                                                                                    
     "country_code2" => "IN",                                                                                                                        
                "ip" => "122.15.151.189"                                                                                                             
},                                                                                                                                                   
  "timestamp" => "31/May/2019:05:12:22 -0700",                                                                                                       
    "request" => "/favicon.ico",                                                                                                                     
      "ident" => "-",                                                                                                                                
       "auth" => "-",                                                                                                                                
      "agent" => "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36\"",          
   "referrer" => "\"http://example.com/\"",            
 "@timestamp" => 2019-05-31T12:12:22.000Z,                                                                                                           
"httpversion" => "1.1",                                                                                                                              
       "verb" => "GET"
```

}

And Now when tried to load make a visualizer in KIBANA geoHash doesn't work as geoip.location is not defined as "type": "geo_point". I have already inserted the whole data. So is there anything I can do to modify the mapping and update the index. 
what I understood is I need to add an extra field in grok and make "geoip.location" field and reparse the whole log again. but is there any way to create a column in existing Elastic Index and Merge Data from 2 columns?

```
Like geoip.location2 merged from geoip.location.lon and location.lat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you cannot modify the mapping for fields that are already present in the index
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_updating_existing_field_mappings

However, you can update the mapping of the index by adding another field. You can check the [exact syntax based on the version of Elastic that you're using](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-put-mapping.html), but for me on Elastic 6.2 the following worked:

```
PUT geo_test1/_mapping/geo_test1
{
  "properties": {
    "geoip": {
      "properties": {
        "location_geo": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can use [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) and a small painless script to fill the data in the new "location_geo" field based on the data already present in the geoip.location:

```
POST geo_test1/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "String lat = ctx._source.geoip.location.lat.toString(); String lon = ctx._source.geoip.location.lon.toString(); ctx._source.geoip.location_geo = lat + ',' + lon",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: "script":{
    
    "source":"ctx._source.geoip.location_geo = [ ctx._source.geoip.longitude , ctx._source.geoip.latitude ]","lang":"painless"},
  "query":{
    "match_all":{}
  }

Thanks ....you saved my day

Comment: Yeah, I saw that the geo_point can be represented in a few different ways and I had trouble with the object one, but the string one worked for me and then I could use it in the visualization, but if the array works better for you that is fine as well. Glad I could help.

Comment: ctx._source.geoip.location.lat.toString() this caused some error to me actually. they said ".lat" makes a parse error .that why googles and found this one... infact  "_update_by_query" is something new to me as i just started using ELK.